# Internal search is not finding .aspx pages using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using below example and I am finding only HTML pages and I am not able to find .aspx extention pages in my website internal search.

Below example tried:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/29d7e0/asp-net-internal-page-search/

Already mention in Web Config Also:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="FilesTypesToSearch" value=".htm,.html,.asp,.shtml,.aspx"/>
    <add key="DynamicFilesTypesToSearch" value=".asp,.shtml,.aspx" />
    <add key="BarredFolders" value="aspnet_client,_private,_vti_cnf,_vti_log,_vti_pvt,_vti_script,_vti_txt,cgi_bin,_bin,bin,_notes,images,scripts"/>
    <add key="BarredFiles" value="localstart.asp,iisstart.asp,AssemblyInfo.vb,Global.asax,Global.asax.vb,SiteSearch.aspx" />
    <add key="EnglishLanguage" value="True" />
    <add key="Encoding" value="utf-8" />
</appSettings>
```